# How to find all child of a table column in sql server table?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql database table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LedgerGroups](
    [GroupName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL primary key,
    [GroupParent] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

The records in the table are

***`-----GroupName------   ---GroupParent---`***

```
Bangalore Customers    Karnataka Customers
Chennai Customers      Tamilnadu Customers
Customers              NULL
Ernakulam Customers    Kerala Customers
Hubli Customers        Karnataka Customers
Karnataka Customers    Customers
Kerala Customers       Customers
Kollam Customers       Kerala Customers
Nagercoil Customers    Tamilnadu Customers
Suppliers              NULL
Tamilnadu Customers    Customers
Tirunelveli Customers  Tamilnadu Customers
```

How can i query the table so that i can get all the child of a particular value. For ex, if i give `Customers` it should return all rows whose parent is Customers and childs of its childs and so on..

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is in the sqlfiddle of my accepted answer.please replace with Customers. IS it possible to accomplish the same in ef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
DECLARE @Group VARCHAR(50)
SET @Group = 'Karnataka Customers'

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[LedgerGroups]
  WHERE GroupParent = @Group
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B.*
  FROM CTE A
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[LedgerGroups] B
  ON A.GroupName = B.GroupPArent
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

And [here is a working sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c270/9) for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself.  This query will return all the Parents and any children they may be associated to:

```
SELECT Parent.GroupName, Parent.GroupParent
,Children.GroupName, Children.GroupParent
from LedgerGroup as Parent
LEFT JOIN LedgerGroup as Children on Parent.GroupName = Children.GroupParent
--  WHERE Parent.GroupName = ''
```

Comment: no, i want to recursive do, until the GroupName has no children