# CTE to return all items in hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table with a recursive hierarchy (i.e. ID, ParentID). For any item in this hierachy, I want to be able to bring back a list of everything UP AND DOWN the hierarchy along with the level for each row. Assume that a parent can only ever have a single child.

Take for example the following:

```
ID    ParentID
--------------
1     NULL
2     1
3     2
4     NULL
5     4
6     5
```

Given ID 1, 2, or 3, I want to return:

```
ID    ParentID    Level
-----------------------
1     NULL        1
2     1           2
3     2           3
```

I've done this before, but I can't remember how. I know the solution involves a CTE, I just can't get it right! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all child of a table column in sql server table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625775/how-to-find-all-child-of-a-table-column-in-sql-server-table)

Comment: @cadrell0. I need parents and children for any given ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
;with cte as 
(
    select *, 1 as level from @t where id = @yourid
    union all
    select t.*, level - 1
    from cte 
        inner join @t t on cte.parent = t.id
),
cte2 as
(   
    select * from cte
    union all
    select t.*, level+1
    from cte2 
        inner join @t t on cte2.id = t.parent

)
    select id,parent, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by level) level
    from (  select distinct id, parent, level from cte2) v
```

Comment: Excellent, it works perfect. Just to be cheeky... can you think of a way to optimise this slightly by removing the need for the nested select at the end?

Comment: Depends if you want them in order or not?

Comment: I'm using the results of this query to return further information, so I will be eventually returning the data (with associated data) in date order. So to put it simply, no, I just need the ID and Level.

Comment: you could do `select distinct id, parent, 1+ level- (select MIN(level) from cte2) as Level from cte2`  (and actually, you can order that by level anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The most barebones version of the CTE query I could come up with is:

```
WITH Ancestry (AncestorID, DescendantID)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ParentID, ID
    FROM
        dbo.Location
    WHERE
        ParentID IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        P.AncestorID, C.ID
    FROM
        dbo.Location C
    JOIN
        Ancestry P on C.ParentID = P.DescendantID
)
SELECT * FROM Ancestry
```

The result is a list of all Ancestor/Descendant relationships that exist in the table.

The final "SELECT * FROM Ancestry" can be replaced with something more complex to filter, order, etc.

To include reflexive relationships, the query can be modified by adding two lines to the final SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Ancestry
UNION
SELECT ID, ID FROM dbo.Location
```

Comment: I made this query into a view, but not sure if this is best practice or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH Recursive_CTE AS (
     SELECT
          child.ExecutiveId,
          CAST(child.ExecutiveName as varchar(100)) BusinessUnit,
          CAST(NULL as bigint) ParentUnitID,
          CAST(NULL as varchar(100)) ParentUnit,
          CAST('' as varchar(100)) LVL,
          CAST(child.ExecutiveId as varchar(100)) Hierarchy,
      1 AS RecursionLevel
     FROM Sales_Executive_level child
     WHERE ExecutiveId = 4000 --your Id which you want to get all parent node
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT
      child.ExecutiveId,
      CAST(LVL + child.ExecutiveName as varchar(100)) AS BusinessUnit,
      child.ParentExecutiveID,
      parent.BusinessUnit ParentUnit,
      CAST('' + LVL as varchar(100)) AS LVL,
      CAST(Hierarchy + ':' + CAST(child.ExecutiveId as varchar(100)) as varchar(100)) Hierarchy,
      RecursionLevel + 1 AS RecursionLevel
     FROM Recursive_CTE parent 
     INNER JOIN Sales_Executive_level child ON child.ParentExecutiveID = parent.ExecutiveId                           
    )
    SELECT * FROM Recursive_CTE ORDER BY Hierarchy  
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 300);
```